# How can I work with .cer files locally in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to integrate a payment gateway into WordPress using a plugin. It works on the production server but not locally. The plugin needs to read some .CER files.

Problem is that on my (local) machine, PHP throws an error saying that the file can't be found. I tried XAMPP and WAMP but they don't seem to work. I'm sure the path to the files is correct.

I used `print_r` to display the path to the file and I'm sure it's correct. What am I missing?

This is the error:

```
Error while loading X509 public key certificate! Reason:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file in C:\wamp64\www\test\wp-content\plugins\sn-wc-mobilpay\Mobilpay\Payment\Request\Abstract.php on line 446
```

Comment: Probably a line ending issue.

Comment: Thanks. Would that be a problem at the end of the file or anywhere?

Comment: Well, your `.cer` looks to be base-64 PEM encoded, so only at end-of-line.